# Generate series of date in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

```
create table ASSIGNDATES (
P_DATE date );

insert into ASSIGNDATES (P_DATE)
values('29-08-2021'),('29-09-2021');
```

I have a table with value of date with one month difference, here I want to generate date series.

Requirement is it should print 5 continuous days then it should leave 2 days then again 5 days.

For example I want output like this:

```
 29-08-21
 30-08-21
 31-08-21
 01-09-21
 02-09-21 //2days gap 
 05-09-21 
 06-09-21
 07-09-21
 08-09-21
 09-09-21 //2days gap
 12-09-21
 13-09-21
 14-09-21
 15-09-21
 16-09-21 //2days gap
 19-09-21
 20-09-21
```

Comment: These `5 continuous days' are from Monday to Friday?

Comment: Generate, enumerate, select needed.

Comment: @McNets yes assume it as any 5days as working days

Comment: @Akina can i get any solution codes, because i'm new to this

Comment: Do you need in (1) working days within the period (Mon-Fri, even when the period starts not from Mon); (2) 5 days then 2 days gap (for any day of the week of the first day of the period)?

Comment: @Akina (2) 5 days then 2 days gap (for any day of the week of the first day of the period) i need this one

Answer (score 1):

```sql
with CTE as ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () rn
              FROM generate_series('2021-01-01'::timestamp, '2021-02-02', '1 day') gs("date") )
SELECT "date"
FROM cte
WHERE rn % 7 BETWEEN 1 AND 5
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=aca098faf658ca953960e702b5cf9997

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do something like this (all of the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=12915d82f8f92ed1e39ab6d06d7ac66c)):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  GENERATE_SERIES
  (
    (SELECT MIN(p_date) FROM assign_dates),
    (SELECT MAX(p_date) FROM assign_dates),
    '1 DAY'
  ) AS tab (the_date);
```

Result:

```
     the_date
2021-08-29 00:00:00+01
2021-08-30 00:00:00+01
2021-08-31 00:00:00+01
2021-09-01 00:00:00+01
2021-09-02 00:00:00+01
...
... snipped for brevity
...
```

and then you will want to do something like the following:

```
SELECT the_date, EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM the_date), TO_CHAR(the_date, 'Day')
FROM
(
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    GENERATE_SERIES
    (
      (SELECT MIN(p_date) FROM assign_dates),
      (SELECT MAX(p_date) FROM assign_dates),
      '1 DAY'
    ) AS tab01 (the_date)
) AS tab02
WHERE EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM the_date) BETWEEN 1 AND 5
ORDER BY the_date;
```

Result:

```
         the_date      date_part      to_char
2021-08-30 00:00:00+01     1           Monday   
2021-08-31 00:00:00+01     2          Tuesday  
2021-09-01 00:00:00+01     3        Wednesday
2021-09-02 00:00:00+01     4         Thursday 
...
... snipped for brevity
...
```

You can vary your `WHERE` clause as appropriate for the days you wish to eliminate - and you won't want **both** the `date_part` and `to_char` results. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41182042/470530), [this](https://database.guide/get-the-day-from-a-date-in-postgresql/) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workweek_and_weekend) helpful.

### EDIT:

It was pointed out to me that the 2 day gap had to be 5 days **after** the start of the period, so I've adjusted the SQL accordingly (see fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=41f01af85c4d814a3f3438fd147fd646)):

```
SELECT 
  the_date, rn, rn % 7 AS mod7 -- you can leave out the rn's for the final query!
  , TO_CHAR(the_date, 'Day')
FROM
(
  SELECT
    the_date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY the_date) AS rn
  FROM
    GENERATE_SERIES
    (
      (SELECT MIN(p_date) FROM assign_dates),
      (SELECT MAX(p_date) FROM assign_dates),
      '1 DAY'
    ) AS tab (the_date)
) AS tab_01
WHERE rn % 7 BETWEEN 1 AND 5
ORDER BY the_date;
```

Result:

```
         the_date      rn   mod7      to_char
2021-08-29 00:00:00+01  1      1       Sunday   
2021-08-30 00:00:00+01  2      2       Monday   
2021-08-31 00:00:00+01  3      3      Tuesday  
2021-09-01 00:00:00+01  4      4    Wednesday
2021-09-02 00:00:00+01  5      5     Thursday 
2021-09-05 00:00:00+01  8      1       Sunday   
2021-09-06 00:00:00+01  9      2       Monday   
...
... snipped for brevity
...
```

So, we can see that the result starts on Sunday, runs 5 days till Thursday and then skips Friday and Saturday and starts again on the Sunday - as requested. Thanks to @Akina for pointing that out! Also, thanks to @ypercube for pointing out a potential `ORDER BY` issue with the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

Comment: OP needs "5 days then 2 days gap (for any day of the week of the first day of the period)".

Comment: @Akina - thanks for that! Upvoted your answer! :-)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ No, it shouldn't. If you look at `rn`, it goes from 1-5, 6 & 7 are removed by the `WHERE` and then you have 8-9 (rest snipped) which is what we want! [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2ed890507b47a87b549ec23027bb0fc9) is what you get if partitioning by the_date - `rn` is 1 for everything!

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Corrected. Your point about a more complex query is well made. I'm blue in the face telling people that a query should always have an `ORDER BY` - Guess I should heed my own advice! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that generates a series of dates, avoiding these two days. Keep in mind that these two days could be a parameter of the function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION genDates(t1 date, t2 date)
RETURNS setof date
AS $$
  WITH dt AS
  (
    SELECT d::date, extract(dow from d) dow
    FROM generate_series(t1::timestamp, t2::timestamp, '1 day') AS gs(d)
  )
  SELECT d 
  FROM dt 
  WHERE dow <> extract(dow from t1+5) and dow <> extract(dow from t1+6)
$$
LANGUAGE sql
IMMUTABLE;
```

Now you can use it in this way:

```
SELECT * FROM genDates('2021-08-29'::date, '2021-09-29'::date)
```

And this is the result:

| gendates |
| --- |
| 2021-08-29 |
| 2021-08-30 |
| 2021-08-31 |
| 2021-09-01 |
| 2021-09-02 |
| 2021-09-05 |
| 2021-09-06 |
| 2021-09-07 |
| 2021-09-08 |
| 2021-09-09 |
| 2021-09-12 |
| 2021-09-13 |
| 2021-09-14 |
| 2021-09-15 |
| 2021-09-16 |
| 2021-09-19 |
| 2021-09-20 |
| 2021-09-21 |
| 2021-09-22 |
| 2021-09-23 |
| 2021-09-26 |
| 2021-09-27 |
| 2021-09-28 |
| 2021-09-29 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=b61d6a5a476ddf6c52a28d033b02013c)*